# TextField sale truncado al generar reporte en ambientes linux

Tags: jasper-reports

tengo la siguiente situacion:

Cuando genero un reporte en el cual un textfield se desborda, generalmente uno espera que genere o se pase al renglon de abajo, es decir, si no cabe en su tamaño continua hacia abajo, ya que asi es como esta configurado, lo cual es el comportamiento esperado,
el detalle que tengo es que en mi ambiente local(windows) esto si sucede, pero al momento de subirlo al servidor(CentOS) la descripcion sale recortada, ya estuve realizando varias cosas pero aun no queda

Alguien que haya pasado por la misma situacion que me pueda brinda ayuda??

Comment: Estás seguro que estás usando los mismos archivos  `.jasper`?

Comment: Asi es, tanto el *.jrxml como el *.jasper son los que estan en ambos ambientes

Comment: Hmmm, qué versión de la librería tienes en cada lado? Y con qué versión de iReport (o JasperStudio o como se llame) creaste los reportes?

Comment: 6.3.0 es la version que se tiene para lo que me preguntaste :D

Comment: Estuve investigando y probablemente la solucion tenga que ver con los font extensions, siendo asi lo que no entiendo es donde configuraria, actualmente uso windows y jaspersoft studio, genero el archivo *.jasper y en mi codigo mando llamar dicho archivo el cual se genera al compilar el reporte, lo que no entiendo realmente es al momento de pasarlo a produccion donde haria esa parte del reporte, ya que el .ear que deployo ahi va el archivo de jasper, pero no se donde iria la fuente para el reporte, no se si me di a entender.

Comment: Ooooh ok, no me pasó igual pero tuve un problema así alguna vez. El reporte usa fuentes del sistema. En los estilos del campo deben indicar varias opciones de fuentes, preferible de las que siempre tiene disponibles Java. Son las fuentes del OS (/etc/fonts o C:\Windows\Fonts). Si no lo haces, debes embeber la fuente en tu aplicación (importarla en jasper al diseñar, luego exportarla como jar y ponerla en el classpath de la aplicación)

Comment: Disculpa eso del classpath de la aplicacion te refieres agregarlo como libreria, o como haria lo que comentas?

Comment: Tal cual. Jasper permite exportar fuentes como librería.